# Can a Javascript based UWP project access the service worker?

Tags: javascript, uwp, progressive-web-apps

When the PWA site cannot be reached and you restart UWP app, it triggers the 404 error message. Obviously, the service worker cannot be activated to deliver content when you restart the UWP as it cannot fetch the js as the fetch is not be intercepted.

So I thought what might be clever would be to add the service worker js and an index.html page to the project that would trigger the local copy of the service worker code so fetch would be in play. I could then reset the document location which would use the cached content from previous use. But navigator.serviceWorker is not defined. Confused as the service worker is fine when using the content URI.

Is there a way to start offline? As I understand it, the cache should still be there.

Comment: I think It's impossible.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too. I have a JS UWP app that runs from a local index.html, but the local Service Worker code does not run (the Service Worker API is not present). This is the case even if targeting the latest version of Windows 10 (for PC): 10.0.18362.0